# Java Selenium test input with disapeared placeholder

Tags: java, selenium

I have a problem with Selenium tests for Java when using standalone-webdriver-firefox docker image v.2.53.0. The problem is when I want insert text to input with placehoder. And this placehoder sometimes appear or not. I tried clean input before  insert text but the result was the same. I increased wait time but that not help. When I using APIwebdriver this problem not appear.

These are my methods

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[contains(@id, 'redirect-uri')]")
private List<WebElement> inputTextRedirectUriElements;


public EdEnvironmentPage enterRedirectUri(String redirectUri) {
        WebElement webElement = inputTextRedirectUriElements.get(inputTextRedirectUriElements.size() -1);
        webElement.sendKeys(redirectUri);

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].blur(); return true", webElement);

    WaitUtil.waitUntilPageIsLoaded(driver);
    return this;
}

 public EdEnvironmentPage enterRedirectUriWithoutHttps(String redirectUri) {
    WebElement webElement = inputTextRedirectUriElements.get(inputTextRedirectUriElements.size() -1);
    webElement.clear();
    webElement.sendKeys(redirectUri);

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].blur(); return true", webElement);

    WaitUtil.waitUntilPageIsLoaded(driver);
    return this;
}
```

WaitUtil

```
public static void waitUntilPageIsLoaded(WebDriver driver) {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.and(
        ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("loading-completed")),
        ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("loader"))
    ));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by APIWebDriver?

Comment: It's mean Selenium firefox drivers from maven [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver). I forget add this

Comment: Are you using the same versions of Selenium/Firefox in both environments.

Comment: Yes, both using 2.53.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolve change selenium version to 2.53.1